# ASP.NET MVC 5 plugin framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my company we have to develop a ASP.NET MVC 5 web application which must have a number of plugins.

We want these plugins to have the following features.

1. Each plugin can be deployed in a separate folder;  No need to copy plugin assembly to bin folder, the plugin files keep same structure as an ordinary website;
2. Dynamically install/uninstall plugin after website gets running;
3. Plugins share same master/layout;
   I have found an article that describes a similar solution, but it depends on plugin framework which is based on OSGi.NET which is not open source.

Is there a plugin framework that has the above features?

Comment: IIRC, nopCommerce has a similar setup (using plugins) which may be worthwhile examining.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) is very good.

This is example of how to build MVC website with plugins architecture:
http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=104

http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=130

I had the same task few weeks ago and now I have working solution, so ask, if you have more questions.

UPD

In my case I want users to be able to add extensions to the app without any dependencies or configuration files. All you need to do is copy extension's folder into the main project's extensions folder. Each extension might contain dlls, views (in separate views folder), content (styles, images etc). Moreover, each extension might have one or more db types support and this can be configured with just copying of files too. Also, my app contains some backend, and this backend should be extensible with the extensions too. So every extension have to tell the main application what it can offer for the frontend and for the backend.

I have spent a lot of time for this, but now it works very good.

Comment: Hello links which you posted don´t work :(. I have question about how did you solved that each module have custom db logic, tables, entities (do you use shared DBCONTEXT?) and each module share some common fuctionality like Authorize attribute, Permissions etc. And another one how to solve module routes. Thanks for share ! If you have some notes, tips, code samples I wiil be very gratefull! Thanks

Comment: @MartinHaščák Hi! You can look at my ExtCore project: https://github.com/ExtCore/ExtCore (it contains everything you asked). I will be happy to answer your questions related to this project.

Comment: @DmitrySikorsky ExtCore is for .net Core version, can you guide me how  i can use the above in mvc4/5 also the docs on your sites have coming soon... tag

Comment: @Dmitry Sikorsky  ExtCore = Asp.net Core, not MVC 5

Comment: @DougBeard Yes, it is. (I have written it.) But the approach works for the MEF too, because the previous version (not open source one) was based on MEF. DI implementation is not so important. The general thing is common architecture of this solution.